# Jackson vs. Spring HATEOAS vs. Polymorphism

Tags: java, polymorphism, jackson, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

When I want to deserialize an Entity with a polymorph member, Jackson throws a `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException`, complaining about a missing type info (...which is actually present in the JSON -> see example).

```
Unexpected token (END_OBJECT), expected FIELD_NAME: missing property '@class' that is to contain type id  (for class demo.animal.Animal)\n at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: demo.home.Home[\"pet\"])"
```

All actual work is done by a PagingAndSortingRepository from Spring HATEOAS.

I use spring-boot V 1.2.4.RELEASE, which means jackson is V 2.4.6 and Spring HATEOAS is V 0.16.0.RELEASE.

Example:

I have a pet at home:

```
@Entity
public class Home {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private Animal pet;

    public Animal getPet() {
        return pet;
    }

    public void setPet(Animal pet) {
        this.pet = pet;
    }

}
```

That Pet is some Animal - in this case either a Cat or a Dog. It's type is identified by the @class property...

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@class")
public abstract class Animal {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}

@Entity
public class Cat extends Animal {

}

@Entity
public class Dog extends Animal {

}
```

Then there is this handy PagingAndSortingRepository, which allows me to access my home via REST/HATEOAS...

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "home", path = "home")
public interface HomeRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Home, Integer> {

}
```

To confirm all that stuff is working, I have a test in place...

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = DemoApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class HomeIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext ctx;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(ctx).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testRename() throws Exception {

        // I create my home with some cat...
        // http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schweizerdeutsch#Wortschatz -> Büsi
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder post = post("/home/")
                .content("{\"pet\": {\"@class\": \"demo.animal.Cat\", \"name\": \"Büsi\"}}");
        mockMvc.perform(post).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isCreated());

        // Confirm that the POST request works nicely, so the JSON thingy is correct...
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder get1 = get("/home/").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        mockMvc.perform(get1).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentTypeCompatibleWith(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$._embedded.home", hasSize(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$._embedded.home[0].pet.name", is("Büsi")));

        // Now the interesting part: let's give that poor kitty a proper name...
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder put = put("/home/1")
                .content("{\"pet\": {\"@class\": \"demo.animal.Cat\", \"name\": \"Beauford\"}}");
        mockMvc.perform(put).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isNoContent());
        // PUT will thow JsonMappingException exception about an missing "@class"...

        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder get2 = get("/home/").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        mockMvc.perform(get2).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentTypeCompatibleWith(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$._embedded.home", hasSize(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$._embedded.home[0].pet.name", is("Beaufort")));

    }

}
```

Interestingly I can create my home with the cat as a pet, but when I want to update the name of the cat it cannot deserialize the JSON anymore...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you update `home` when you want to change the animal's name? Your `put` would create a new animal.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to attempt a half-answer.

When processing a PUT (probably PATCH as well), `spring-data-rest-webmvc` merges the given JSON data into the existing entity. While doing so, it strips all properties that don't exist in the entity from the JSON tree *before* passing it to the Jackson `ObjectMapper`. In other words, your `@class` property is gone by the time Jackson gets to deserialize your object.

You can work around this (for testing/demonstration purposes) by adding your `@class` property as an actual property to your entity (you have to rename it of course, say `classname`). Now everything will work fine, however your entity now has an otherwise useless `classname` property, which is probably not what you want.

Using the `@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)` approach also won't work, for a similar reason (except this time the entire wrapper object is removed). Also as with the original approach, GET and POST will work fine.

The whole thing looks like a bug or `@JsonTypeInfo` not supported in `spring-data-rest-webmvc` situation.

Maybe somebody else can shed some more light on this.